# Using the method of C/C++ libraries in C # return a random value, instead of the above in return

Tags: c#, c++, c

When I call a function from C++ DLL to C#, it returns a random value such as:

> 17700591018967041

**Source.cpp** (a part of DLL C++, which I use in my C# application):

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) uLong ZEXPORT Source()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs** (C# application):

```
...Declaration class...

    [DllImport("dll_adler32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern ulong Source();

    static void Main()
    {
          ulong t1;
          t1 = Source(); // returns a random value
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is weird since `Source()` doesn't take argument. Is there an override hidden somewhere...?

Comment: Thomas,I fixed it, thank you. The question is: why returns random number, when must 1.

Comment: ulong in c# is 64 bit, in c and c++ unless that typedef is declared as "long long" is 32 bit. Also make your calling convention explicit.

Comment: What do you mean `instead mine`?

Comment: I tryed to fix my question, sorry for my wrongs in text. I mean, thaе I give a value 1 in return.

Comment: What is a `uLong`?  That's not a standard C/C++ type.  It's a typedef for something.

Comment: Adriano Repetti, thank you. It work. i change this in to uInt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C++ code your `uLong` is 32 bits while a `ulong` in C# is 64 bits.  So `Source` will only write 32 bits, but C# will read 64 bits.  `17700591018967041` in hex is `0x3EE298 00000001`.  The low 32 bits are the `1` value returned by `Source` and the upper 32 bits are whatever random data C# happened to read.  Change your p/Invoke definition to:

```
[DllImport("dll_adler32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint Source();
```

Comment: And this shows why you should prefer hex over decimal. Once you realize that `0x3EE298 00000001` isn't totally random but the top 32 bits are, the solution is obvious.